# Ruby on Rails - run Ruby File.open only when link is clicked

Tags: ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

In my application I have a `link_to` that I use for voting purposes. This `link_to` does different things if `user_signed_in?` or not.

When user **IS** signed in, they can vote, otherwise a modal opens for them to **sign up or login**.

What I want to achieve is to count how many users has **clicked** on voting buttons but didn't vote because of sign up.

I was thinking to do a easy `ruby` operation and add **1** and `date` for each click.

*Here is my link:*

```
= link_to_unless has_voted?(@image.id, 1), (image_tag 'vote/thumb-up.png'),user_signed_in?? vote_image_path : File.open("public/count.txt", "a+") { |file| file.puts ([1, Date.today]).join }, data: {target: user_signed_in?? "" : "#login-modal", toggle: user_signed_in? ? "" : 'modal'}, remote: true
```

Everything works fine when user is signed in, but when I want to run:
`File.open("public/count.txt", "a+") { |file| file.puts ([1]).join }`
is when things goes wrong.

This adds the number, but instead of adding number to `count.txt` file only when `link_to` is clicked, it also adds 1 for **each visit/refresh**.

How can I make `File.open("public/count.txt", "a+") { |file| file.puts ([1]).join }` only run when `link_to` is **clicked** and not on each visit/refresh.

I have been thinking to make a `route` and add the `function` there and redirect back, but then I can't open sign up modal and at same time I do not want to refresh the page and send user back and forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like it would be a good fit for [server-generated JavaScript responses](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3697-server-generated-javascript-responses).

To summarize the concept:

- create a link which triggers an AJAX request to the server (using `link_to` with `remote: true`)
- let the server decide whether to count the vote or increase the voted-but-not-logged-in-counter and show the modal. Based on this it will generate the corresponding JavaScript which will be executed on the client
- the client receives a JavaScript response and executes it

It is your decision whether the modal functionality is already loaded from the start and the server just returns `showLoginModal();` or whether the server response contains the whole JavaScript to create the modal.

Comment: You could also follow this plan partially (AJAX request to vote and then server decides what to do with it), but then have the server return successfully (HTTP code of 200) if it's counted and an error (401 or 403) if the user needs to sign in. Client-side code then checks the response and shows the login modal if it gets that error response. Either way can work well; it's just a question of where you want to define your logic.